# How to edit this name in Samsung Android Phones

Tags: samsung

[image]

How to edit this name in Samsung Android Phones

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That is the default name for your Cellular Modem. For more information, check this out: [What is CP and AP and what are these options used for?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120680/what-is-cp-and-ap-and-what-are-these-options-used-for)

Comment: many person doing this why i ask here